# strange behavior with numpy roll and masked array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code (i.e. it's just a dummy code to demonstrate my problem)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np

#define array, -999 being a missing value
a=np.array([5.,-999.,7.,8.])
print "array:"
print a
print

a=np.ma.masked_values(a,-999.)
print "masked array:"
print a
print

#define new missing value
bad=1e30
a.set_fill_value(bad)

#roll array
a=np.roll(a,1,axis=0)

#plug-in new missing value 
a=a.filled()

print "array after rolling with new missing value (1e30):"
print a
```

On my 32 bit machine with numpy 1.4.1, I get the expected output:

```
array:
[   5. -999.    7.    8.]

masked array:
[5.0 -- 7.0 8.0]

array after rolling with new missing value (1e30):
[  8.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+30   7.00000000e+00]
```

On my 64 bit machine with numpy 1.6.1 I get

```
[   5. -999.    7.    8.]

masked array:
[5.0 -- 7.0 8.0]

array after rolling with new missing value (1e30):
[  8.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+20   7.00000000e+00]
```

So, my fill value for the masked array of 1e30 changed to 1e20 after rolling the array. I'm I doing something wrong, or is this a known bug?

Raphael

Comment: Interesting, on 64bit + numpy 1.4.1 works fine. Might be a numpy bug. What versions of Python?

Comment: 64bit + numpy 1.8.0 fails the same way as yours. Probably a numpy bug.

Comment: 64bit + numpy 1.7.0 and Python 3.3.0 fails the same way.

Comment: where should I report such a bug?

Comment: Numoy uses github for issue tracking: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues; you could also mention it on the numpy mailing list: http://mail.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/numpy-discussion